# Android Certificate Issues : How to upgrade from debug to release certificate

Tags: android, jenkins

i've a problem with android certificate. We have published a build to one organisation with the debug certificate using jenkins. Now im facing the following issues:

- Im unable to find which debug.keystore is used while build the project using jemins.
- And now i want to certify the build with new keystore and make sure that the application should just upgrade the previous one and should not erase the previous data.

Please help.

Comment: The `debug.keystore` file should be in the `~/.android/` directory of the user account used to run Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that - upgrade is only possible if certificates match.

Answer (score 1):

1,
There is `CERT.RSA` file in APK's `META-INF` folder, unzip it, and use keytool to check the fingerprint of the certificate:
    `keytool -printcert -file your-path\CERT.RSA`

Every keystore has it's own fingerprint, so it can used to distinguish keystores.

keytool is included in JDK.

2, 
Upgrade a package with different certificate is definitely not allowed by Android.

Comment: thanks for reply. How can i know which debug.keystore is used by jenkins while building..?